# Forwarding traffic from a host to a host's container

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, docker

I have two hosts in a network `192.168.0.0/24`:

- Host A `192.168.0.15`
- Host B `192.168.0.13`

And there is a remote ssh tunnel from `B` to `A`:

```
ssh -R 192.168.0.13:8080:192.168.0.15:8002 192.168.0.13 -N
```

and that tunnel works.

Host `A` runs a container `nginx` that runs nginx on a port 80. I would like to forward a traffic from `192.168.0.15:8002` to that nginx server. How to do it?

So,

if someone send a `GET request` with `curl 192.168.0.13:8080` he will get response from nginx run on `192.168.0.15` in a container. The flow should be:

```
192.168.0.14 (for example) ---GET--> 192.168.0.13:8080
192.168.0.13 --(SSH TUNNEL)--> 192.168.0.15:8002 
192.168.0.15:8002 -----------> 172.17.0.2:80 (nginx container)
172.17.0.2      ------------> 192.168.0.15
192.168.0.15    ------------> 192.168.0.13
192.168.0.13    ------------> 192.168.0.14
```

P.S.
I have to use iptables- I cannot change an existing tunnel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the REDIRECT extension.

You can change the destination for all TCP connections from port 8002 to port 80 with the following command on Host A:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8002 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80
```

If you want the redirect to also work for connections from the localhost, add

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8002 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80
```

Comment: Thanks! Is the `PREROUTING` omitted in the case of looback?

Comment: `PREROUTING` is omitted when a locally generated packet is destined for localhost. Diagrams can be useful for seeing which chains and tables are entered and when

Comment: Do you know a diagram that embrace a localhost case?